# Windows 8 purple screen

Tags: windows-8

I have completely new laptop with Windows 8 (1 week old). Suddenly today the screen went completely purple, the cursor was visible though (Almost like a blue screen, except no error message). I couldn't do anything, not even <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>del</kbd>. I restarted the computer and after a few hours, the same problem occured again. I have searched a lot of forums, including Microsoft's, with no luck. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Most probably hardware problem - bring it back to warranty.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried refreshing it? if not go to find, search refresh, follow instructions, and refresh your pc. Check if the problem is gone.

Answer (score -2):

I had this same situation this morning. I could get to desktop screens and ran all malware systems with no improvement.

The solution was to restore my computer to an earlier time and all was well. The usual Windows * start-up boxes returned, however all of my sites lost all saved signons and some saved information.